# How can ordinary Xero users view the calculation of leave?

Tags: xero

How can ordinary, non admin, users view how their leave entitlements are calculated?

I can see how much leave I am entitled to, but not how that's calculated.

https://help.xero.com/au/PayrollLeaveTransactions tells users to

> Go to Reports, then click All Reports.

But I can't see "report" anywhere.

Clicking on the "Leave" tab lists requests, but for for "complete" requests, it doesn't display how many hours leave it consists of.